# How to load a DSA Key from KeyInfo using openSSL

Tags: openssl, digital-signature, dsa

I am trying to verify an XML digital signature using openSSL. When I actually use EVP_VerifyFinal, I get the error code 0D07209B (ASN1_get_object:too long). He's how I load the the KeyInfo from the cert:

```
<KeyInfo>
 <KeyValue>
  <DSAKeyValue>
    <P>/KaCzo4Syrom78z3EQ5SbbB4sF7ey80etKII864WF64B81uRpH5t9jQTxeEu0ImbzRMqzVDZkVG9xD7nN1kuFw==</P>
    <Q>li7dzDacuo67Jg7mtqEm2TRuOMU=</Q>
    <G>Z4Rxsnqc9E7pGknFFH2xqaryRPBaQ01khpMdLRQnG541Awtx/XPaF5Bpsy4pNWMOHCBiNU0NogpsQW5QvnlMpA==</G>
    <Y>butK4tBy8dwSJFjTRpTvmYZYnsDGO4CzMVgcD8EQ2UJrQZd0ZapQI/Ea2DZzQBTFjjdnNkFuNOtjVI615lhiBQ==</Y>
  </DSAKeyValue>
 </KeyValue>
</KeyInfo>
```

My (pseudocode) method for loading the PDSA:

```
 pDSA = DSA_new();
 pDSA.p = BN_bin2bn(base64Decode(text of P element));
 pDSA.q = BN_bin2bn(base64Decode(text of Q element));
 pDSA.g = BN_bin2bn(base64Decode(text of G element));
 pDSA.pub_key = BN_bin2bn(base64Decode(text of Y element));
```

Using BN_bn2hex after this gives me the values:

```
p: FCA682CE8E12CABA26EFCCF7110E526DB078B05EDECBCD1EB4A208F3AE1617AE01F35B91A47E6DF63413C5E12ED0899BCD132ACD50D99151BDC43EE737592E17
q: 962EDDCC369CBA8EBB260EE6B6A126D9346E38C5
g: 678471B27A9CF44EE91A49C5147DB1A9AAF244F05A434D6486931D2D14271B9E35030B71FD73DA179069B32E2935630E1C2062354D0DA20A6C416E50BE794CA4
pub_key: 6EEB4AE2D072F1DC122458D34694EF9986589EC0C63B80B331581C0FC110D9426B41977465AA5023F11AD836734014C58E376736416E34EB63548EB5E6586205
```

the, validating the signature:

```
  <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <SignedInfo>
      <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
      <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#dsa-sha1"/>
      <Reference URI="">
        <Transforms>
         <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
       </Transforms>
       <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>      
       <DigestValue>uooqbWYa5VCqcJCbuymBKqm17vY=</DigestValue>
      </Reference>
    </SignedInfo>    
    <SignatureValue>L4h4TFDj5rDKCHm0D+aH2LeSfAMV2t0V5S91Afu6U0NlfpjxdTXRUA==</SignatureValue> 
    <KeyInfo>
     <KeyValue>
      <DSAKeyValue>         
       <P>/KaCzo4Syrom78z3EQ5SbbB4sF7ey80etKII864WF64B81uRpH5t9jQTxeEu0ImbzRMqzVDZkVG9xD7nN1kuFw=</P> 
       <Q>li7dzDacuo67Jg7mtqEm2TRuOMU=</Q> 
       <G>Z4Rxsnqc9E7pGknFFH2xqaryRPBaQ01khpMdLRQnG541Awtx/XPaF5Bpsy4pNWMOHCBiNU0NogpsQW5QvnlMpA==</G>
       <Y>POKkQtGuazaz6OEWi91P4C9z1tREpeP9f7L3piRD/3TiNFzvt0BmYzNO0CoPSjEVTXYKIRo/+HXK6MhBRk2eUw=</Y>
     </DSAKeyValue>
    </KeyValue>
   </KeyInfo>
  </Signature>
</Envelope>
```

Here's how I validate the signature:

```
  pkey = EVP_PKEY_new;
  EVP_PKEY_set1_DSA(pkey, pdsa)
  EVP_MD_CTX_init(ctx);
  EVP_VerifyInit(@ctx, EVP_sha1)
  EVP_VerifyUpdate(@ctx, digest of SignedInfo);
  bytes = unbase64(text of SignatureValue)
  EVP_VerifyFinal(@ctx, btes, length(bytes)}, pKey);
```

Verify final returns the following errors:

```
0D07207B:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_get_object:header too long)
0D068066:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:bad object header)
0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error)
```

So either I am loading the certificate or the signature value wrongly. According the spec, the signature value is "The signature value consists of the base64 encoding of the concatenation of two octet-streams that respectively result from the octet-encoding of the values r and s in that order" - but I cannot find anywhere in the openSSL documentation what should be passed to EVP_VerifyInit for the signature value for a DSA signature. I found one reference in an email archive that pointed to RFC 3279 which appears to specify the same format, so far as I can tell (Dss-Sig-Value  ::=  SEQUENCE  { r       INTEGER, s       INTEGER  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you've actually already answered your own question. You should split the received signature in two (two 20 byte values as specified by XML-DSig), and then create the ASN.1 signature. It would indeed consist of the following ASN.1 DER structure:

```
Dss-Sig-Value ::= SEQUENCE {
    r INTEGER,
    s INTEGER
}
```

DER is a "tag, length, value" structure. Now a SEQUENCE has tag encoding `30`, then a DER length of the two *encoded* integers, and r and s are INTEGER values, encoded with tag `02` then the length followed by the *shortest representation of a signed big endian integer*.

As programming ASN.1 is tricky at best and downright vulnerable as worst (all versions up to 1.0.1 of OpenSSL had a memory corruption bug, Windows NT authentication of old was completely broken) I'll show how to create this structure using pseudo code:

- convert the base64 to bytes (unsigned chars, forty of them)
- use the first 20 bytes for `rData`, the second for `sData` (or better, split in half)
- strip all leading (leftmost) `00` valued bytes of `rData` and `sData`
- if the leading byte is `80` or over, prefix a `00` byte to `rData` an `sData`
- create a structure `30 LL { 02 LL { rData } 02 LL { sData } }` where LL is the size in bytes of the structure between braces

I'll leave it to you to perform the encoding. Note that this will work as long as `LL` is never the value of 128 or over (which should be the case for DSA).

You may want to switch to ECDSA by the way; note that it would likely require the same structure above. Also note that I cannot see if the input of the digest is correct, but it should at least resolve the ASN.1 error.

---

In the end you should get [this structure](http://lapo.it/asn1js/#302C02142F88784C50E3E6B0CA0879B40FE687D8B7927C03021415DADD15E52F7501FBBA5343657E98F17535D150) for you current signature (note that this one is a bit boring as it doesn't contain any initial values of `00` and it does not contain any initial bytes equal to or higher than 128 either).

Comment: That's really great, thanks. I couldn't find which asn.1 encoding I should use, and I really appreciate you doing the work for that. I can verify the signature now. However I have one follow up question - when I sign, using EVP_MD_CTX_init(ctx), EVP_SignInit(ctx, EVP_sha256), EVP_SignUpdate(@ctx, bytes of digest), EVP_SignFinal(ctx, sig, len, pKey), I get a len of 70, which is an asn.1 structure that contains 2 32 byte keys, not 20 byte keys. But they're only supposed to be 20 bytes?

Comment: Probably depends on the key used. 20 bytes relates to a value of 160 bits for parameter q. You are now probably using a key of 2048 / 256 bits. For a long time only DSA keys with 1024 / 160 bit sizes were used, and the XML spec seems to still live in those times :)